# How to set bootstrap-switch to off using Java?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I am using [this](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) switch. I have tried using

```
$("[id='switchId']").bootstrapSwitch('setState', false);
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setState : 
use this $("[id='switchId']").bootstrapSwitch("state", true);